# MySQL json extract/search not matching

Tags: mysql, json

this is driving me crazy.
Can someone explain, why the first call returns a path, but when selecting the path from a table, no path is found?

(MySQL-Version 5.7.20)

Working as expected:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(
  '{"mm": [{"id":"1","field":"test","value":33}]}',
  'one', '1', null, '$.mm[*].id') as path;
  -- output: path== "$.mm[0].id"
```

Not working:

```
drop table test;
create table test(
    id int primary key,
    data json
);

insert into test (id, data) values (1, '{}');
update test set data=JSON_SET(data, '$.mm', json_array()) where id=1;
update test set data=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(data, '$.mm', '{"id":"1","field":"test","value":33}') where id=1;
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', '1', null, '$.mm[*].id') as path from test where id=1;
-- output: path==NULL
-- expected: path== "$.mm[0].id"
```

Pretty sure i did some error here, but i can't figure out which one ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got it... 
One has to cast the string to json in order to have a object type in the table. This is true for append and set. When using JSON_SEARCH the first parameter is automaticly converted to json if it's a string.